# Code running very slow

Tags: performance, matlab, loops

My code seems to run very slowly and I can't think of any way to make it faster. All my arrays have been preallocated. S is a large number of element (say 10000 element, for example). I know my code runs slowly because of the "for k=1:S" but i cant think of another way to perform this loop at a relatively fast speed. Can i please get help because it takes hours to run.

```
[M,~] = size(Sample2000_X);
[N,~] = size(Sample2000_Y);
[S,~] = size(Prediction_Point);

% Speed Preallocation
Distance = zeros(M,N);
Distance_Prediction = zeros(M,1);

for k=1:S
    for i=1:M
        for j=1:N
            Distance(i,j) = sqrt(power((Sample2000_X(i)-Sample2000_X(j)),2)+power((Sample2000_Y(i)-Sample2000_Y(j)),2));
        end
        Distance_Prediction(i,1) = sqrt(power((Prediction_Point(k,1)-Sample2000_X(i)),2)+power((Prediction_Point(k,2)-Sample2000_Y(i)),2));
    end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the major problem was organization of my code. I was performing calculation in a loop where it was absolutely unnecessary. So i seperated the code in two blocks and it Works much faster.

```
for i=1:M
    for j=1:N
        Distance(i,j) = sqrt(power((Sample2000_X(i)-Sample2000_X(j)),2)+power((Sample2000_Y(i)-Sample2000_Y(j)),2));
    end
end

for k=1:S
    for i=1:M
    Distance_Prediction(i,1) = sqrt(power((Prediction_Point(k,1)-Sample2000_X(i)),2)+power((Prediction_Point(k,2)-Sample2000_Y(i)),2));
    end
end
```

Thanks to the community for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix `Distance` does not depend on `k`, so you can easily calculate it outside the main `for`-loop, for instance using:

```
    d = sqrt((repmat(Sample2000_X, [1,M]) - repmat(Sample2000_X', [M,1])).^2 + (repmat(Sample2000_Y, [1,N]) - repmat(Sample2000_Y', [N,1])).^2);
```

I assume `M=N`, because elsewise your code won't work. Next, you can calculate your `Distance_Prediction` matrix. It is rather strange that you calculate this inside the `for`-loop over `k`, because the matrix will be changed in every iteration without using it. Anyway, this will do exactly the same as your code:

```
    for k=1:S
        Distance_Prediction = sqrt((Sample2000_X - Prediction_Point(k,1)).^2 + (Sample2000_Y - Prediction_Point(k,1)).^2);
    end
```